# Match string with values from array in express-validation

Tags: node.js, validation, express

I am using express-validator to validate input to my API, but I have some problems understanding the matches function. I basically need to be able to figure out if a string matches any of the values in an array of accepted values, like shown below, but it doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

```
var schema = {
  "role": {
    in: 'body',
    matches: {
      options: ["administrator", "editor", "contributor", "user"],
      errorMessage: "Invalid role"
    }
  }
}

req.check(schema)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `matches.options` constructs a regex. You can pass in your regex as the first element of the array. Try this:

```
var schema = {
  "role": {
    in: 'body',
    matches: {
      options: [/\b(?:administrator|editor|contributor|user)\b/],
      errorMessage: "Invalid role"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That made my day :)

Answer (score 8):

As an alternative you can use this schema:

```
 var schema = {
  "role": {
    in: 'body',
    isIn: {
      options: [["administrator", "editor", "contributor", "user"]],
      errorMessage: "Invalid role"
    }
  }
}
```

More on [this issue](https://github.com/express-validator/express-validator/issues/192).

Answer (score 7):

The way I do it is by using `isIn()`

```
check('action').isIn(['like', 'dislike']).run(req)
```

Answer (score 3):

For me the approach described by mr mkhanoyan didnt worked properly, in tests I passed string value with additional symbols and it passed, so that was wrong beheviour

I managed to create custom enum validator:

```
app.use(expressValidator({
  customValidators: {
    enum: (input, options) => options.includes(input)
  }
}));
```

Also in controller, I use it like this:

```
req.checkBody('productType').notEmpty().enum(['car', 'tire']);
```

Tests are failing with '!car', 'cahsjhacardasdas' and other invalid inputs

Answer (score 3):

Since this post is a while ago and some things changed I thought it's time for an **Update:**

According to the [docs](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/check-api.html) of express-validator 5.2.0 the following syntax for [validating a schema](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/schema-validation.html) is recommended (Please note that it's important to call bodyparser **before** express-validator and the function-name **checkSchema**):

app.js

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const expressValidator = require('express-validator');

/* Initialize/Mount BodyParser for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded */
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

/* Initialize/Mount BodyParser for parsing application/json */
app.use(bodyParser.json());

/* Initialize/Mount Express-Validator for validating user input from the frontend */
app.use(expressValidator());
```

in the route (here's a register example):

```
/* INFO: Require express validator */
const { check, checkSchema, validationResult } = require('express-validator/check');

var Schema = {
  "role": {
    in: 'body',
    matches: {
      options: [/\b(?:administrator|editor|contributor|user)\b/],
      errorMessage: "Invalid role"
    }
  }
}

module.exports = (router) => {
  router.post('/register', [
    // INFO: check validty
    check('username',"Invalid username").isLength({min: 5}),
    check('email',"Invalid  e-mail").isEmail(),
    check('department',"Invalid department").isLength({min: 3}),
    checkSchema(Schema),
    check('password',"Invalid  password").isLength({min: 5})
    ], 

    function(req, res, next) {  
      const errors = validationResult(req);
      if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
         // DO THIS
      }
      else {
         // DO THAT
      }
     });
    return router;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following is the solution that I implemented in typescript.

```
enum RoleOptions {
  client = "CLIENT",
  vendor = "VENDOR",
  operator = "OPERATOR",
  admin = "ADMIN",
  superAdmin = "SUPERADMIN",
}

import express, { Request, Response } from "express";
import { body } from "express-validator";

const router = express.Router();
router.post(
  "/api/updateroles",
  [
    body("roles")
      .notEmpty()
      .isArray()
      .custom((roles) => {
        return roles.every((role: RoleOptions) =>
          Object.values(RoleOptions).includes(role)
        );
      })
      .withMessage("Please provide vaild roles"),
  ],
  async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    res.status(200).send({ message: "SUCCESS" });
  }
);

export { router as updateRolesRouter };
```

We can also use it inside the function

```
async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    await check('roles').notEmpty().isArray().custom(value=>{
        return value.every((v: RoleOptions)=>Object.values(RoleOptions).includes(v));
    }).run(req);
    res.status(200).send({ message: "SUCCESS" });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Clean and Simple Approach! Just use the `.isIn` function provided by express-validator and pass **an array of strings** to match the value with them.
Tip: You can use the `withMessage()` function to send a custom error message if the validation fails!

```
check('role')
.isIn(['admin', 'user', 'donor', 'doctor']),
.withMessage('role must be admin | user | donor | doctor'),
```